# Unable to create clusters in Hazelcast over the Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I am trying to use Hazelcast on Kubernetes. For that the Docker is installed on Windows and Kubernetes environment is simulate on the Docker. Here is the config file `hazelcast.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.7.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
    </properties>


    <network>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false" />
            <tcp-ip enabled="false"/>
                
            <discovery-strategies>
                <discovery-strategy enabled="true"
                    class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
                    <!-- 
                <properties>
                    
                    <property name="service-dns">cobrapp.default.endpoints.cluster.local</property>
                    <property name="service-dns-timeout">10</property>
                  </properties>
                  -->
                </discovery-strategy>
              </discovery-strategies>
        </join>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

The problem is that it is unable to create cluster on the simulated environment. According to my deploment file it should create three clusters. Here is the deployment config file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        image: testapp:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5701
        - containerPort: 8085

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: hazelcast
      port: 5701
    - name: test
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8085
      targetPort: 8085
```

The output upon executing the deployment file

```
Members [1] {
        Member [10.1.0.124]:5701 this
}
```

However the expected output is, it should have three clusters in it as per the deployment file. If anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast's default multicast discovery doesn't work on Kubernetes out-of-the-box. You need an additional plugin for that. Two alternatives are available, Kubernetes API and DNS lookup.

Please check [the relevant documentation](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes) for more information.

Comment: I think I also did the same with the use of xml . If you can answer it more clearly with some example.

Comment: You can find a complete example in [this guide](https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes/).